# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional when try to send email with flask_mail

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I ask this question 3 day ago and no one answer my question I developing a simpel website that use fastapi and i mount flask on fastapi i this in my app.**init** :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from app.config import DevelopmentConfig
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.wsgi import WSGIMiddleware
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = FastAPI()

flask_app = Flask(__name__)

app.mount("/", WSGIMiddleware(flask_app))
```

this is run file :

```
from app import app
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

i have route for sending email conformation when i test the app i face this error :

```
 msg = Message("Confirm Email",sender=site_mail)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

i use [flask mail dcoument](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) and i dont know how can i fix the problem and why i get this error

this is my view file :

```
from app import flask_app
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort, flash
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer, TimestampSigner
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

mail = Mail()
mail.init_app(flask_app)
serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(flask_app.config["SECRET_KEY"])
timestamp = TimestampSigner(flask_app.config["SECRET_KEY"])

@flask_app.route("/confirm", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def confirm():
    image = get_photo("cafe")
    user_email = current_user.email
    message = "Please Confirm your Email address with the link blow"
    token = serializer.dumps(user_email, salt="email-confirm")
    unsubscribe_token = serializer.dumps(user_email, salt="unsubscribe")
    link = url_for("confirm_email", token=token, _external=True)
    unsubscribe = url_for("unsubscribe", token=unsubscribe_token, _external=True)
    site_mail = flask_app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"]
    print(site_mail)
    msg = Message("Confirm Email", sender=site_mail, recipients=user_email)

    msg.body = render_template("public/email/single-news.html",
                               user=current_user,
                               link=link,
                               image=image,
                               message=message,
                               unsubscribe=unsubscribe)

    msg.html = render_template("public/email/single-news.html",
                               user=current_user,
                               link=link,
                               image=image,
                               message=message,
                               unsubscribe=unsubscribe)

    mail.send(msg)

    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

and its config for flask app :

```
class Config:
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://root:tool789@localhost/city"
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    JSON_AS_ASCII = True
    JSON_SORT_KEYS = True
    IJSONFY_MIMETYPE = 'application/json'
    SECRET_KEY = "b'\xf1L\xdb5D\x96M\xe5\xd1\x9f\x16+\xf4%A\x1e\xb9\xafm\xb8g\x1ct\x0e'"
    MAIL_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com"
    MAIL_USERNAME = "myemail"
    MAIL_PASSWORD = "password"
    MAIL_PORT = 465
    MAIL_DEBUG = False
    MAIL_USE_SSL = True
    MAIL_USE_TSL = False
```

this is full error i get :

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60517 - "GET /confirm HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 429, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 443, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\wsgi.py", line 71, in __call__
    await responder(receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\wsgi.py", line 98, in __call__
    await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(self.wsgi, environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\wsgi.py", line 132, in wsgi
    for chunk in self.app(environ, start_response):
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2551, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2531, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 290, in decorated_view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(func)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\app\views.py", line 260, in confirm
    msg = Message("Confirm Email", sender=site_mail, recipients=user_email)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

if i just use flask not with fastapi i get this error :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2023 18:21:09] "GET /confirm HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2551, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2531, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 290, in decorated_view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(func)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\favoritecafe\app\views.py", line 258, in confirm
    msg = Message("Confirm", sender=site_mail, recipients=user_email)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

Smells like the error is due to the `recipients` argument in the `Message` constructor. The `recipients` argument should be a **list** of email addresses, but you are passing a single string (`user_email`). So wrap your string into list and you should be good:

```py
msg = Message("Confirm Email", sender=site_mail, recipients=[user_email])
```

Check docs: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/

Comment: i change it but i get same error